# How to listen to an even in JQuery, specifically, add a p element after a button and add the ability to remove it again on click

Tags: html, jquery

In this piece of code I must add a p element by clicking the button, making the element appear after the button (the line under the button). Then I must be able to remove the p again by clicking any of the words in this newly appeared paragraph. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
      $("#btn").after(" <br/r> " + "Click on me to remove");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <p class="test">Test 5: Listen for Event</p>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Click on the button below to insert a new paragraph after this and add the ability to remove the paragraph when it is clicked.</p>
     <p><button id="btn">Insert a new p element after this button</button></p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css selector ~ to make sure to target ONLY the `p` AFTER the button. Then simply add an event handler to `#btn ~ p`.

The most important part of this is event delegation. By delegating the event to `document` (or the parent) you can catch ALL future `P` elements that are added to the dom. Without delegation, the event handlers are tied to ONLY the elements in the DOM at the point of adding the event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
      $("#btn").after("<p>Click on me to remove</p>");
    });
    
    $(document).on("click","#btn~p",function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
    
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <p class="test">Test 5: Listen for Event</p>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Click on the button below to insert a new paragraph after this and add the ability to remove the paragraph when it is clicked.</p>
     <p><button id="btn">Insert a new p element after this button</button></p>
 </div>
```